# recv() for larger amount of data not working

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming, recv

I am implementing one server with new designed protocol. As per protocol, client sends header followed by data. Header contains meta information including *size of data* as well.

We provide sample client, but client program can be written by third party as well. So, we can not totally rely on *size of data* field provided in header.

Now, I'm facing one problem with `recv()` system call.

```
      #define SOCKET_CHUNK_SIZE 4096
      void * value;

 1    value = (void *) malloc(hdr.size);
 2    total_bytes_read = 0;
 3    while(total_bytes_read < hdr.size) {
 4        n = recv(newsockfd, value + total_bytes_read, SOCKET_CHUNK_SIZE, 0);
 5
 6        //fprintf(stderr, " %ld + %d = %ld\n", total_bytes_read, n, total_bytes_read + n);
 7
 8        total_bytes_read += n;
 9
10        if(n == 0 || n < SOCKET_CHUNK_SIZE)
11            break;
12        if(n < 0)
13            send_error_response(newsockfd);
14    }
15
16    fprintf(stderr, "%ld", total_bytes_read);
```

This works perfectly for a small amount of data (like 9420 bytes), but fails for larger amount.

**Observation:**

Let client send some big amount of data like 604697 bytes (hdr.size):

1. `recv()` can read only 65280 bytes. i.e. fprintf on line #16 prints 65280. (I checked SSIZE_MAX on my machine and it's 2147483647 so it's far more greater than SOCKET_CHUNK_SIZE)
2. I tried using MSG_DONTWAIT flag in `recv()` call, but result is same.
3. I tried using `read()` system call in place of `recv()`, result is same.
4. When I uncomment line #6 it works perfectly!! (But this line (and line #16) is for debugging purpose only. I cannot keep it in a final versions)
5. If I use MSG_WAITALL flag in `recv()`, it works, but blocks while reading last chunk as last chunk size is lesser then SOCKET_CHUNK_SIZE (604697 = 147 * 4096 + 2585). So, I cannot use this flag unless I depends on *size* provided in header from client and do change in `recv()`.

Data supplied by client can be binary as well so we can not place some kind of indication as end of data.

Anyone who have ideas / solutions are welcomed. As I mentioned, we have solution - rely on client header - but I will prefer it only when I don't find any other ways.

Ravi

Comment: `n < SOCKET_CHUNK_SIZE` this condition is not good. Data received by one `recv` call can be less than specified number of bytes.

Comment: You shouldn't increment `total_bytes_read` until you know that `n > 0`.

Comment: @EJP. If `n < 0` it will send error and won't accept data

Comment: @Ravi If `n < 0` it is incorrect to execute `total_bytes_read += n`. No two ways about it. You should test `n < 0` first.

Answer (score 2):

Almost all of the observations are perfectly explainable:

1. I'd like to skip that one as I'm not sure if I got it correct and as I am considering it a s a secondary error for now.
2. recv is not guaranteed to fill the whole buffer (unless you set MSG_WAITALL). It returns after some bytes are received. Hence the second part of your condition in Line 10 is preventing you from receiving further data if you don't set MSG_WAITALL. Setting MSG_WAITALL makes recv to return only after the whole buffer is filled (in your case SOCKET_CHUNK_SIZE). As your payload's size is not always a multiple of SOCKET_CHUNK_SIZE, your last recv call will hang until the connection dies.
3. This is due to the condition in Line 10 i mentioned above.
4. Stick with recv, this is the corret way to do it
5. I guess uncommenting Line 6 changes the timing of execution that way that **by chance** more data than SOCKET_CHUNK_SIZE arrives at the socket.

So the best thing from my point of view would be to use recv without the MSG_WAITALL flag and accept receiving chunks smaller than SOCKET_CHUNK_SIZE.